# issue when multiple recipients for my app mail- Objective c

Tags: ios, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am facing a problem when multiple recipients for my mail, i have two attachments there by default.Is there anything i have to do when iam sending a mail to multiple recipients other than the below code; (I have to select or type recipient id's from UI)

```
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
            {
            [self printPdfAndCsv];// code to generate pdf & csv

            MFMailComposeViewController* mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            // attaching PDF File.
            [mailComposer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.pdfFilePath]
                                   mimeType:@"Application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdfName-%@.pdf", selectedProjectName ]];
            // attaching CSV File.
            [mailComposer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.csvFilePath]
                                   mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"csvName-%@.csv", selectedProjectName ]];
            [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
           }
```

Iam a starter in iPhone development, so i need your  valuable help.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: when iam sending to two recipients, it receives only by one receiver.

Comment: Have you tested with different receivers? Perhaps there is a problem with one of the email addresses you tested. Maybe the email ended up appearing as junk mail (spam). There is nothing wrong with your code (other than "Application/pdf" should be "application/pdf"). Once the user taps Send, it's out of your control.

Comment: @rmaddy: great!!!! you are right... now i can find it in my spam box.
thanx so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) on his comment,

- There may be problem with one of the email addresses we tested.
- Maybe the email ended up appearing as junk mail (spam).

  Once the user taps Send, it's out of our control.
  (and in my case; i found the mails that i have sent were in spam box)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sent mail to multiple user then you can use:

```
[mailController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@address.com",@"email1@address.com",@"email@address.com",nil]];
```

Comment: thanx,, but strVendorEmail?

Comment: It will be email address of Recipients. You can pass more than one email address .

Comment: use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and get selected email id of the contacts and pass that contacts to Recipients. Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@gmail.com",@"xyz@gmail.com",nil]; 
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```